# Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - can't access environment variables from container

Tags: python, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

I have tried to move our Python/Django app to Docker on AWS Elastic Beanstalk (single Docker container). I've written a basic `Dockerfile` as below, scraped together form various tutorials:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /var/app
WORKDIR /var/app
ADD requirements.txt /var/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /var/app
EXPOSE 8000

RUN python3 manage.py migrate --settings=finimize_django.settings.aws --noinput


CMD python3 manage.py runserver --settings=finimize_django.settings.aws
```

This builds fine up until the `migrate` `RUN` command, at which point the app errors because it can't find the environment variables from the EB UI.

I've noticed there is an example AWS image [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-eb-python-dockerfiles), which I would rather not use (for a bunch of reasons e.g. simplicity, being able to use a similar image locally, wanting control etc.). Looking at the Dockerfile this uses I can't see how they have solved this problem either.

Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AWS documentation for elastic beanstalk Python platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html), environment properties are accessible via Python's os.environ dictionary. For more information, go to http://docs.python.org/library/os.html.

General information regarding setting environment properties in Elastic Beanstalk can be [found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html).

Try using both of these guides to change how your settings file is written in order to get the migrate RUN statement to work.

If these don't provide you the clues you need, please post the exact error message and perhaps the lines from the settings file in your question and we might be able to better help you. Also the goal of accessing the settings (DB Connection info, keys, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a small working docker file  that I currently use for a small single app eb deployment of a production instance.

One point about the environment variables make sure they are defined in the container or in the .env file.

The example bellow uses gunicorn and runs on port 80. You would need to put in your ENV variables for db/cache/email/other. Plus also make sure that you have correct security groups setup to authroize EB access to your RDS.

One point to make, is you should not be running migrate/migrations on every EB deployment. I would suggest to run them separately and test them before you do as migration mistakes/errors can seriously mess up your production/dev server which is something you do not want.

```
        FROM python:3.6

    RUN apt-get update && \
        apt-get -y install libev-dev gcc gcc+ python3-dev g++ && \
        rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


        WORKDIR /app
        ADD . /app
        RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

    ENV DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS *
    ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE config.settings.production

    EXPOSE 80
    ENTRYPOINT ["python", "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", "config.wsgi", "-b 0.0.0.0:80" ,"-w=3", "--chdir=/app"]
```

Comment: Good point on the migrate command. Do you run this manually each time you deploy a migrated variable - or are you just suggesting deploying to a test environment first?

Comment: I run manually if I need during the deploy. As I want to handle the errors that are received from makemigrations, as they occur. I normally test it on my staging prior as well. I also make it a point to design my models so migrations do not fail if possible. But you never know, especially when integrating with third party libraries. Last thing you want is to run into some arbitrary migration error and brick your production.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually sussed what was wrong here - I don't think you can access env vars unless you're in the build phase (i.e. not in `RUN` commands, unless you preface with `ONBUILD`).

To solve the issue, I moved my `manage.py` commands into a bash script which I use as an entrypoint:

```
FROM python:3

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /var/app

RUN pip3 install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv /var/app

ADD . /var/app

EXPOSE 8000

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/var/app/scripts/aws_start.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/var/app/scripts/aws_start.sh" ]
```

Then in my `aws_start.sh` I have:

```
cd /var/app

. bin/activate

pip install -r requirements.txt

python3 manage.py createsu --settings=finimize_django.settings.aws
python3 manage.py migrate --settings=finimize_django.settings.aws --noinput
python3 manage.py runserver --settings=finimize_django.settings.aws
```

This seems to work fine now